# Adding multiple ViewController on UI interface builder

Tags: swift, user-interface, viewcontroller

I'm trying adding multiple ViewController on my app UI interface builder but I don't find it in the library. I need to make many ViewControllers to add background images and some elements.

Comment: Search up “uiviewcontroller” and it should pop up

Comment: On the Interface Build, click the top menu View >  Show Library then search "uiviewcontroller", you could also learn the short there which is shift+cmd+L

Comment: Thanks a lot and I really appreciate your comment

Comment: I did that but it still don't appear unfortunately, maybe because, I have chosen Swift UI instead av storyboard!! I was thinking also, maybe I need to create a new file for storyboard despite the Swift UI!!